# Mysql search varchar column strategy

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I can't find decent strategy for searching titles.

I have table for movies.
Each movie has 5-10 alternative names that are stored in movie_names (id, name, name_clean, movie_id) table.

To normalize all names I use script that converts all names in ascii, removes whitespace, punctuation, etc. and place it in name_clean.

And on search I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(movie_id) FROM movie_names WHERE `name_clean` LIKE '%f%' ORDER BY views DESC
```

And then I use ids and select with "where in" movies table.

Although this strategy works, but because of my name cleaning the search is very wide. I want to improve it without name cleaning, but wonder if I can improve it better.

For example I was thinking about search LIKE 'f%', but then I will need to explode every movie name in words.
And if I have movie name "My very fat big movie name" I need to make this much of additional rows:

"My very fat big movie name"
"very fat big movie name"
"fat big movie name"
"big movie name"
"movie name"
"name"

Also on people table I use query

```
 SELECT * FROM people WHERE `name1` LIKE '%f%' OR name2 LIKE '%f%' ORDER BY views DESC
```

While searching movies the speed is okay, but it is very wide and selects too much results (search column is latin_swedish), with people table it's very slow (columns are utf8) and there are more rows.

How would you organize search in mysql.

Comment: I would store the alternate names in a separate table that has a foreign key that relates back to the main movie table. For both the movie and people search I would have the front-end not start searching until a minimum of 2 or perhaps even 3 characters entered. That should really reduce the amount of hits while still giving you a decent result set.

Comment: thanks but this is already done, except people table (in people table i query columns)

Comment: Maybe ["12.9 Full-Text Search Functions"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) is interesting for you?

Comment: Only one column for the various names -- this will avoid the messy and slow `ORs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for halp, especially sticky bit.

Here solution worked for me.

New table with id and name column with fulltext. I query with match against in boolean mode "query*". Works very well. No need for elastic.